# PHP making a chart with Google charts

Tags: php, google-visualization

I am trying to create a [Google line chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) for the number of views my website gets per day. I am not quite sure how to do this.

here is the code that is makes everything work:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2004',  1000,      400],
      ['2005',  1170,      460],
      ['2006',  660,       1120],
      ['2007',  1030,      5412]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

now I would like to change this to list the total number of views to my website per day, and then compare it with the unique number of views to my website per day.

The queries would look like:

```
$total = mysql_query("SELECT id, userID, ip, date FROM views WHERE userID!='1'");
$unique = mysql_query("SELECT id, userID, ip, date FROM views GROUP BY ip");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total is wrong, to get it per day you should do something like

```
SELECT count(*) as nr, date FROM views WHERE userID!='1' GROUP BY date
```

Your unique visitors are not so easy to calculate. I would create a view to use in my query,
the View would be something like

```
SELECT count(*) as nr, data, ip FROM views WHERE userID!='1' GROUP BY date, ip ORDER BY date
```

Lets say you give the view above the name unique_views. the nr column is not actually used but it is nice to have for other things.

To get the unique visitors you should do

```
SELECT count(*), date FROM unique_views GROUP BY date ORDER BY date
```

Both the queries above should have the same number of records because both of them are based on the same table, so if you ran them both you should be able to

```
$total_per_day = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as nr, data, ip FROM views WHERE userID!='1' GROUP BY date, ip ORDER BY date");
$unique_per_day = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as nr, date FROM unique_views WHERE userID!='1' GROUP BY date ORDER BY date");
```

You can then do a

```
for($i=0;$i<count($total_per_day);$i++) {
   $result[] = "['" . $total_per_day[$i]["date"] . "'," . $total_per_day[$i]["nr"] . "," . $unique_per_day[$i]["nr"] . "]"
}
$str = implode(",", $result);
```

Comment: Thanks for all of your time! Unfortunately I haven't been able to get it working. :\

Comment: It is rather technical and I cannot test my code as it is rather hard.   If you do take anything from a 10 year programmer is use google's own Analytics, do not try to build your own. You do not have the expertise and they have all the things for free. Insert the code in your pages and you are set. With the data properly kept in their system you can find tens of examples on how to integrate it with their own graph.

Comment: If you really want the data in your own system, still use their system and you can easily query their db and save it your own db.